# How can i append a $_POST variable to a $_SESSION array each time the form is sent?

Tags: php, session-variables, http-post-vars

For  about 2 hours i'm struggling with this problem.
I want to insert my $_POST variables in a $_SESSION array,and append each new data sent from the form to the session variable.
Now,when i define my session variable as a array,do i say like this?
$_SESSION['name'];
or like this
$_SESSION['name'] = array();

I have two POST variables,and i want to insert each one in a session array.

Here is the form:

```
<form action="action.php" method="POST" >
<label>Moovie name: <input type="text" name="name" /></label><br />
<label>Price: <input type="text" name="price" /></label><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And here is action.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = array();
$_SESSION['price'] = array();

$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

array_push($_SESSION['name'], $name);
array_push($_SESSION['price'], $price);

print_r($_SESSION['name']);
echo "<br>";
print_r($_SESSION['price']);

?>
```

Note:
If i say

```
$_SESSION['name']; instead of $_SESSION['name'] = array();
```

i get Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in action.php
Again, is $_SESSION['name'] an array from the beginning?

Comment: Check if [`is_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), if not, then set them to arrays and continue, if it has already been initialized, that `= array()` code won't be ran, so you won't null it out. (or, with how PHP works, you may simply just use `$_SESSION['name'][] = $name;` etc and if it isn't an array, it will be made in to one.)

Comment: @Jon `is_array()` will still trigger a notice is the key doesn't exist at all, use `isset()` as well/instead: `if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) { $_SESSION['name'] = array(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are emptying the session arrays every time this script runs.

To avoid this, check if the arrays are already present in the session:

```
<?php

session_start();


if (!isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['name'] = array();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['price'])) {
    $_SESSION['price'] = array();
}    


$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

array_push($_SESSION['name'], $name);
array_push($_SESSION['price'], $price);

print_r($_SESSION['name']);
echo "<br>";
print_r($_SESSION['price']);

?>
```